# How to join two vertical cells in latex?

Tags: tables

I have a table looks like exactly what I want, except for the first column from the left, the word `Grain` is not in the middle of the cells (I used `cline{3-11}` to hide the line but how to make the word `Grain` aligned in center ?

Thanks in advance!

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\label{T:equipos}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\textbf{} & \textbf{} & \multicolumn{3}{ c |}{\textbf{Apple}} & \multicolumn{3}{c |}{\textbf{Corn}} & \multicolumn{3}{c |}{\textbf{Water}}\\ 


\cline{3-11}
\textbf{} &  & \textbf{Liquid} & \textbf{Fruit} & \textbf{Grain} & \textbf{Liquid} & \textbf{Fruit} & \textbf{Grain} & \textbf{Liquid}& \textbf{Fruit} & \textbf{Grain} \\
\hline


Grain & Max & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{3-11} % this one
       & Avg & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline


Cereal & Max & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \cline{3-11}
      & Avg & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline


\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It would be very uselful if you make your code compilable, by adding `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use command `\multirow{2}{*}{Grain}` to get the word `Gain` centered in the two table cells.

See the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\label{T:equipos}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\textbf{} & \textbf{} & \multicolumn{3}{ c |}{\textbf{Apple}} & \multicolumn{3}{c |}{\textbf{Corn}} & \multicolumn{3}{c |}{\textbf{Water}}\\ 
\cline{3-11}
\textbf{} &  & \textbf{Liquid} & \textbf{Fruit} & \textbf{Grain} & \textbf{Liquid} & \textbf{Fruit} & \textbf{Grain} & \textbf{Liquid}& \textbf{Fruit} & \textbf{Grain} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Grain} & Max & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{3-11} % this one
                       & Avg & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Cereal} & Max & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \cline{3-11}
                        & Avg & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I accepted the answer, but could not give you rate up because I am new :(